# What professions will help a Demonology Warlock?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am trying to phrase this question in a way that makes it not subjective. I am not looking for "the most fun" or "best" profession for a Warlock to practice in WoW. What I am looking for is to get more information on what profession will benefit a warlock the most in terms of content progression. Be it getting additional stats on armor or being able to create potions - what will help the Warlock the most if they invest their time in? I just recently hit level 85 and after reading about all of the professions, I am still not quite sure as to which will help me the most.

Comment: "most in terms of content progression" - Being level 85, could you elaborate on which content you are looking to progress through with these professions?

Comment: I agree with @James Do you want it for GOLD, RAID, PVP or FOR FUN ?

Comment: In WoW "content progression" is almost universally used for raiding.  Nothing else is "progression" as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best profession, bar none, for content progression is Blacksmithing.  The two additional sockets can be fitted with [epic gems](http://www.wowhead.com/item=71881) that provide a +100 stat point bonus to your Intellect, more than any other profession, and Intellect is the most important stat for a Warlock.  That's because it was originally balanced around non-epic gems that only provided +40 Intellect each.

All of the other professions are balanced around providing ~80 stat points.  If you compare the ring enchants (Enchanting), the upgraded Jewelcrafting gems, etc etc etc, you will find that the majority offer a selection of stats but all will total around ~80.  For your second profession, to maximise your progression stats, you should pick a profession that will give you +80 Intellect.  These are:

- Jewelcrafting (**technically the second best**, because it gives you three [gems with +27 Intellect more](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=73399) than the normal equivalent, coming out to a +81 Intellect bonus)
- Enchanting (2x enchanting ring with +40 Intellect)
- Alchemy ([Mixology](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=53042) used with [Flask of the Draconic Mind](http://www.wowhead.com/item=58086) gives +80 Intellect)
- Tailoring ([a proc that averages out to +80 Intellect](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=75172#))
- Inscription ([a shoulder enchant that has +80 Intellect more](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=86403) than [the equivalent for non-Scribes](http://www.wowhead.com/item=62343))
- Leatherworking ([a bracer enchant that has +80 Intellect more](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=85010) than the equivalent for non-LWers)
- Engineering ([an on-use ability that averages out to +80 Intellect](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=82175))

The worst to pick are the gathering professions because while Skinning ([+80 Critical Strike Rating](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=74495)) and Herbalism ([+480 Haste Rating for 20 seconds every two minutes](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=74497), averaging out to +80 Haste Rating) give you DPS stats, they are not as beneficial as pure Intellect from Blacksmithing or Jewelcrafting, for example, and Mining ([+120 Stamina](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=74496)) does not provide a DPS stat at all.

Comment: I can't provide the full list of profession benefits and stats in the second paragraph because I'm at work, but I'll edit them in later.  For example, I'm pretty sure Enchanting offers +40 Intellect to rings, which would satisfy the requirement for your second profession but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Ok, updated with links for most abilities and full details for professions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a think about what every profession can grant your character and break it into groups like these:

- Armour: Tailoring, alchemy (trinket)
- Enchants: Enchanting(weapons and armour slots), tailoring (leg slot), inscription (spells and shoulder slots), cooking (passive bonuses), jewel crafting.
- passive bonuses: Skinning (+crit rating), Herbalism (healing & +haste rating), Mining (+stam)

You can also look at what would be the easiest to level, perhaps your race has a racial bonus to a particular profession?

Another thing to think about is, with 2 gathering professions you could just make lots of gold to buy the things you require, so funding your needs via gathering (mining, skinning, herbalism).

Having a good read through the [wowwiki page](http://www.wowwiki.com/Profession) will help you get a grasp too.

NB: Enchanting, Jewel crafting are big winners for a class, because they have unique crafted items only the crafter can use. E.g. JC unique gems, Enchanting rings for the crafter only.